# Android move activity with fix background

Tags: android, android-activity, background, animated

I have big background image, I want use it for two activity, like my image when the button pressed, I want to slowly moving activity 2 from left to right the background look like moving from left to right, like android home screen when you swipe your screen, what I need to do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use fragments instead of activities.
In this way you can have a single activity with the fixed background and two fragments with transparent background.